# zend framework 2 - Translation Process

Tags: zend-framework2

i am developing web app with ZF2. It is a multilingual website. I would like to use ZF2 Translator for translation. Because, admin can modify the language variables. So, i planned to use the language folder files. I will update the language files while the admin modifying the language variables. Can anyone suggest ideas for this implementation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Translating based on user input can get a little messy. There is no easy way of doing that right now, as the currently supported formats are all file formats: php files with arrays, a gettext .po file or Tmx/Xliff files. For the easiest access, you would likely store the translations in a database.

You therefore need to write your own loader, loading the translations from the database. An alternative is you will write the translations in a php array and export that to a file, but I would not recommend that. For the database loader, you must implement the [`RemoteLoaderInterface`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/I18n/Translator/Loader/RemoteLoaderInterface.php). In very simple terms:

```
use My\DbTable;
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Loader\RemoteLoaderInterface;
Zend\I18n\Translator\TextDoamin;

class DbLoader implements RemoteLoaderInterface
{
    protected $table;

    public function __construct(DbTable $table)
    {
        $this->table = $table;
   }

    public function load($locale, $textDomain)
    {
        $data = $this->table->loadFromLocale($locale);

        // process $data into $messages
        // $messages is array(key=>value) with key translation key

        $domain = new TextDomain($messages);
        return $domain;
    }
}
```

The db table loads the messages in the locale you specify. If you use text domains, pass that on too. Then you need to configure your `Translator` such it uses this loader too to load the message. Everything else should be fine then. In your views, you can create translations like this:

```
<?php echo $this->translate('my original text'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The SkeletonApp comes with Translation support built-in. However further details on how to use it can also be found in the manual -> http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.i18n.translating.html

I personally keep all my language files in a folder called /language

In your views you could also simply call

```
$this->translate('text_you_want_to_translate');
```